# How to write spark DataFrames to Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql, scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I use Spark 1.3.0
Let's say I have a dataframe in Spark and I need to store this to Postgres DB (postgresql-9.2.18-1-linux-x64) on a 64bit ubuntu machine.
I also use postgresql9.2jdbc41.jar as a driver to connect to postgres

I was able to read data from postgres DB using the below commands

```
import org.postgresql.Driver
val url="jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres?user=user&password=pwd"
val driver = "org.postgresql.Driver"

val users = {
  sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map(
    "url" -> url,
    "driver" -> driver,
    "dbtable" -> "cdimemployee",
    "partitionColumn" -> "intempdimkey",
    "lowerBound" -> "0",
    "upperBound" -> "500",
    "numPartitions" -> "50"
  ))
}

val get_all_emp = users.select("*")
val empDF = get_all_emp.toDF
get_all_emp.foreach(println)
```

I want to write this DF back to postgres after some processing.
Is this below code right?

```
empDF.write.jdbc("jdbc:postgresql://localhost/postgres", "test", Map("user" -> "user", "password" -> "pwd"))
```

Any pointers(scala) would be helpful.

Comment: Have you at least tested your code to ask if is it right or not ?

Comment: Hi @eliasah 
The error I'm getting is below
error: value write is not a member of org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame

Comment: Is spark 1.3 a constraint ? Can't you update to 1.6.2 ?

Comment: @eliasah That is a constraint for now

Answer (score 3):

You should follow the code below.

```
val database = jobConfig.getString("database")
val url: String = s"jdbc:postgresql://localhost/$database"
val tableName: String = jobConfig.getString("tableName")
val user: String = jobConfig.getString("user")
val password: String = jobConfig.getString("password")
val sql = jobConfig.getString("sql")
val df = sc.sql(sql)
val properties = new Properties()
properties.setProperty("user", user)
properties.setProperty("password", password)
properties.put("driver", "org.postgresql.Driver")
df.write.mode(SaveMode.Overwrite).jdbc(url, tableName, properties)
```

Comment: Maybe this is not the best explained answer ever but at least for the one who has down-voted, some comments on why it's been down voted is also good.

Comment: @VishnuJayanand I didn't say that you down-voted it. I'm just asking the one who did to give a reason.

Comment: @eliasah Sorry for no explanation but this code is what I did before I don't remember correctly but I sure that using Map instead of Properties doesn't work with Scala. So that why I give the code what I already did and succeed.

Comment: I am getting this error when I execute the first line of code
error: not found: value jobConfig @giaosudau

Comment: @VishnuJayanand jobConfig just a instance of Config you can replace it by variable you use for db, password, user ...